# android: kSOAP how to get list of country from an string returned by kSOAP response

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

My kSOAP web service return the xml into this format how can I fetch `country_name` from this

```
    anyType{country=anyType{country_name=Egypt; }; 
    country=anyType{country_name=Pakistan; };
    country=anyType{country_name=United Kingdom; };
    country=anyType{country_name=United States; }; }
```

Comment: you can refer this link http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html or http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: can you show your SOAP Response format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arraylist<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){

countries.add(response.getProperty(i).getPropertyAsString(0));


}
```